# Create a database from a DataContext with integrated security

Tags: c#, sql, linq, datacontext

I am trying to create a database from a dbml file into a SQLExpress server that is running on my AD connected machine.

Here is my code:

```
var connString = "server=SQLEXPRESS;database=dbName;integrated security = true";

using (MyDataContext dc = new MyDataContext(connString))
{
      dc.CreateDatabase();
}
```

But I get an error saying

> The user name or password is incorrect

Even if my user is marked as db_creator and sys_admin in the SQL server.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Try this connection string

```
var connString = "data source=.;database=dbName;integrated security = true";
```

Answer (score 0):

could you try it:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
var conString = @"Data Source = .\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=dbName; Integrated Security = true";
con.ConnectionString = conString;

try
{
     con.Open();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: I could create the SQLConnection, but with the same connection string I cannot connect the database, still got the same error message saying  The user name or password is incorrect

Comment: i don't know your database and sqlserver. Please look here:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4416/Beginners-guide-to-accessing-SQL-Server-through-C

it's not too hard. Good luck! :-)

Comment: here is another good link:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s4yys16a(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: I explained myself badly. I could connect to the database using SQLConnection, but not using the data context